# Why does my Transformer output its stylesheet, not the transformation it represents?

Tags: java, xslt

My question in brief: when I build a `Transformer` from a valid stylesheet, and call its `transform(input, output)` method, I seem to get the contents of the stylesheet itself stored in `output`, not the transformation of `input`.

(**Updates at the bottom.  This question is now [answered](/a/29246458/208288).**)

I am doing the most basic of all possible basic invocations of basic `javax.xml.transform` APIs using Java 8.

Here are all the details.

I have a basic XML document that looks like this (as we'll see, it hardly matters):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
<target-store name="foobar">
 <target-key name="abc"/>
  <target-key name="def"/>
 </target-store>  
 <testing>
  <target-store>
   <target-key name="ghi">
    <bogus/>
   </target-key>
  </target-store>
 </testing>
</doc>
```

I have an XSLT file that looks like this, although as we'll see shortly it doesn't really matter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <!-- First the identity transformation. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="target-store">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:with-param name="u" select="'bill'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="p" select="'gates'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="target-key">
    <xsl:param name="u" select="'scott'"/>
    <xsl:param name="p" select="'tiger'"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <username><xsl:value-of select="$u"/></username> 
        <password><xsl:value-of select="$p"/></password>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Plugging these raw values into several different [online XSLT testers](http://xslttest.appspot.com/) produces transformed output of the type I want.  Putting bogus characters into the XSLT file produces an error, so it is getting read and parsed successfully, so it is a valid stylesheet file.)

**If I run the following (elementary) Java transformation code, the *stylesheet* is output, not the transformation it represents.**  Whiskey Tango Foxtrot.

I cannot for the life of me understand why this is.  Here's the code, and then I'll paste the output:

```
public void testRawAPIs() throws Exception {
  final ClassLoader ccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  assertNotNull(ccl);

  final URL foobarXml = ccl.getResource("foobar.xml");
  assertNotNull(foobarXml);

  final URL foobarXslt = ccl.getResource("foobar.xslt");
  assertNotNull(foobarXslt);

  try (final InputStream foobarStream = new BufferedInputStream(foobarXml.openStream());
       final InputStream foobarXsltStream = new BufferedInputStream(foobarXslt.openStream())) {

    System.out.println("*****");

    // db is set up elsewhere as DocumentFactoryBuilder.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().
    final Document foobarDocument = db.parse(foobarStream);
    assertNotNull(foobarDocument);
    print(foobarDocument);

    System.out.println("*****");

    final Document foobarXsltDocument = db.parse(foobarXsltStream);
    assertNotNull(foobarXsltDocument);
    print(foobarXsltDocument);

    System.out.println("*****");

    // tf is set up by JUnit elsewhere as TransformerFactory.newInstance().
    final Transformer t = tf.newTemplates(new DOMSource(foobarXsltDocument)).newTransformer();
    assertNotNull(t);

    final DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

    t.transform(new DOMSource(foobarDocument), result);

    // TODO FIXME: for some reason, this prints out the STYLESHEET.  WTF.
    print((Document)result.getNode());

    System.out.println("*****");

}
```

The `print()` method is straightforward:

```
private static final void print(final Document document) throws Exception {
  print(document, new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")), 2);
}

private static final void print(final Document document, final Writer writer, final int indent) throws Exception {
  final Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
  assertNotNull(transformer);
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", String.valueOf(indent));

  transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));
}
```

Lastly, the output.  As you can see, the raw document is printed first, as I'd expect, followed by the explicitly printed stylesheet, as I'd expect, followed by...a normalized version of the stylesheet (WTF):

```
*****
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<doc>
<target-store name="foobar">
  <target-key name="abc"/>
  <target-key name="def"/>
</target-store>
<testing>
  <target-store>
    <target-key name="ghi">
      <bogus/>
    </target-key>
  </target-store>
</testing>
</doc>
*****
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- First the identity transformation. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="target-store">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:with-param name="u" select="'bill'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="p" select="'gates'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="target-key">
    <xsl:param name="u" select="'scott'"/>
    <xsl:param name="p" select="'tiger'"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <username>
        <xsl:value-of select="$u"/>
      </username> 
      <password>
        <xsl:value-of select="$p"/>
      </password>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
*****
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="target-store">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:with-param name="u" select="'bill'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="p" select="'gates'"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="target-key">
    <xsl:param name="u" select="'scott'"/>
    <xsl:param name="p" select="'tiger'"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <username>
        <xsl:value-of select="$u"/>
      </username>
      <password>
        <xsl:value-of select="$p"/>
      </password>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
*****
```

What have I done wrong in this most basic of tutorial-grade examples?

**Update #1:** In my example here, I am constructing a `Source` for my stylesheet by using a `DOMSource`.  If I switch to using a `StreamSource` to "house" my stylesheet, my output is correct.  Why is this?  Is there something inherently wrong with using a `DOMSource` to wrap a `Document` that is the result of parsing an XSLT stylesheet?

**Update #2:** Thank the Lord; there's a [related question](/questions/12174297/jaxp-transformer-via-domsource-returns-stylesheet).

**Update #3:** `TransformerFactory` allows you to use any `Source` implementation in its [`newTransformer(Source)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer-javax.xml.transform.Source-) method.  But if that `Source` implementation happens to be a `DOMSource`, then you better hope that your caller produced it with a [namespace aware](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware-boolean-) `DocumentBuilderFactory`, or the result of document transformation will be the stylesheet itself.  This is exceedingly weird and smacks of a flaw in the design of these APIs.

Comment: Does using a `StreamSource` (instead of a `DOMSource`) produce a different result? (I mean try using: `final Transformer t = tf.newTemplates(new DOMSource(foobarXsltStream)).newTransformer()` and `t.transform(new DOMSource(foobarStream), result);`). The method is different, and the results may give you a better clue to the problem (it's also more efficient to do it this way).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem.  If the `DocumentBuilderFactory` that (indirectly) built the `Document` in the `DOMSource` was not namespace aware, then you get the stylesheet as your output. This is even though the contract in `Transformer` accepts any kind of `Source`.  _Why_ this is the case is still a bit of a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that although `TransformerFactory` lets you use a [`Source`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html) implementation for your [stylesheet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTemplates-javax.xml.transform.Source-), if you happen (unknowingly, of course) to use a [`DOMSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html) that was constructed by a caller who [did not declare his associated `DocumentBuilderFactory` as namespace-aware](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware-boolean-) then you'll get the output of the stylesheet as your transformation (!).

The moral of the story is: tell your callers what to do (?!) or—if you have any control over the transformation process itself—make sure you don't ever accept a `Source` that is in fact a `DOMSource`.

Comment: Although the answer might be empirically correct (presumably for the version of Xalan that comes with the JDK), I don't understand WHY it is happening. I would expect a message that says the stylesheet is invalid. But another moral of the tale is, avoid DOM like the plague. There is always a better alternative.

Comment: Nor do I!  When I have some time I'm going to dig in to Xalan's implementation and track this sucker down. Hate feeling thick-witted.